# How to hide full toolbar in Chrome custom tab in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to hide full address bar, only body should be visible just like a full screen activity.

I couldn't find `hideToolbar()` method inside `CustomTabsIntent`.

Comment: Their is no option to hide toolbar from chrome custom tab

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently released an update to hide it called trusted web activities. Please follow the guide from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa)

Comment: `Note: Trusted Web Activity is available in Chrome on Android, version 72 and above.`

Comment: And only for websites you own.